# How to extract a database columns(and their data) into a new table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table in ms sql 2008 and I want to take 2 columns(the pk and another column) and put it into a new table.

How can I extract all the data in these columns already and put them in the new database?

Comment: So, new table or new database?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to create a new table then you can try

```
SELECT .... INTO... FROM
```

E.G:

```
SELECT Pk_Column, Other_Column
  INTO NewTable
  FROM CurrentTable
```

If you have already created the table then try `INSERT .... INTO .... SELECT .... FROM`

```
INSERT INTO NewTable   
SELECT Pk_Column, Other_Column   
  FROM CurrentTable
```

Comment: i always forget about the select into syntax

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO targetdb..targettable(personfirstname, personlastname) 
SELECT firstname, lastname FROM sourcedb..sourcetable
```

Comment: Will this do all the information form the specific table or only 1 piece of data at a time?

Comment: If you run the statement as-is, all rows are selected from source table and inserted into target table.  If you want to filter and select only subset of rows, use WHERE clause.  Eg: WHERE FIRSTNAME LIKE 'Brandon%'  (Note: % character is a wild card.)